# How to get image property?

Tags: c#, image, visual-studio-2010

I am working in VS2010(C# windows application).  I want to get image property(all property, like program name, authors, copyright, camera maker etc) and tried the below.

I am getting the below property only. How can i get the other properties of images.

```
 Image img = Image.FromFile("image file path");
 imgMetaData += "Width : " + img.Width;
 imgMetaData += "Height : " + img.Height;
 imgMetaData += "VerticalResolution : " + img.VerticalResolution;
 imgMetaData += "HorizontalResolution : " + img.HorizontalResolution;
```

Any one assist me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can get these via GDI+ which has standardised property codes: http://kajabity.com/2010/01/extracting-image-properties-in-c-2/, properties are here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xddt0dz7(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Well you cant get fill them in code-behind but! you can access them through the aspx inline like html tag <img> and for example you can fill them there like: <img author=<% #Eval("Author") %>

Answer (score 0):

You need to read the EXIF information of the image. You can read an article explaining this technique:

https://www.drewnoakes.com/code/exif/

and this:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xddt0dz7.aspx